# I edit lib varien file Multiselect.php working perfect in local not working in live

Tags: administration

```
/lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Multiselect.php
```

I recently edited **Multiselect** file. its working fine in localhost but doesn't work on live. Is there any other **Multiselect** which is used in magento.

Also I debug the code ( **Multiselect** ). I added **exit** in localhost, but its not **exit**-ing on live. There is some ambiguity.

Comment: Did you edit the file directly or did you place a copy in /app/code/local/......? If you used the last option maybe the local pool is disabled in app/etc/local.xml on your live system.

Comment: I edited the file directly @VladimirKerkhoff

Answer (score 2):

Is this a typo?

```
/lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/multiselect.php
```

should be

```
/lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Multiselect.php
```

If you are working on Windows or Mac locally and live is linux you have a problem with case-mistakes.

Yes and as Vladimir Kerkhoff said, copy the file over to:

```
app/code/local/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Multiselect.php
```

it will be found there and you don't have to touch the core!

Comment: Fabian its Multiselect.php. Sorry my mistake

Comment: but its not working still..